# Visual Studio Code debugger keeps crashing C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

Whenever I run my program with debugging breakpoints, it works until I get to line 39. If I'm not on the debugging pane, where I look at the variables, it works, but once I switch to it the variables say "Error: GDB exited unexpectedly" for their values and the program stops running. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  ifstream fin("measurement.in");
  ofstream fout("measurement.out");
  //number measurements made
  //n lines with day, name, change in milk
  //output total number of changes of most milk
  
  //process input
  //variables for each cows input
  //sort measurements by day
  //for each measurement, change corresponding cow's output variable
  //check which cow has the hightest output currently
  //if different than before, increment count variable
  //output count
  int n;
  int count{0};
  vector<int> days;
  vector<int> changes;
  vector<string> names;
  bool bHighest = false;
  bool mHighest = false;
  bool eHighest = false;
  int bessie, mildred, elsie;
  fin >> n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //Line 38
  {
    int d, c;
    string ns;
    fin >> d >> ns >> c;
    days.push_back(d);
    names.push_back(ns);
    changes.push_back(c);
  }
  for (int currDay = 0; currDay <= 100; currDay++){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if (days[i] == currDay)
      {
        int change = changes[i];
        if (names[i] == "bessie") bessie += change;
        if (names[i] == "mildred") mildred += change;
        if (names[i] == "elsie") elsie += change;
        int currMax = max(bessie, max(mildred, elsie));
        if (bessie == currMax)
        {
          if (!bHighest){
             count++;
             bHighest = true;
             mHighest = false;
             eHighest = false;
        }}
        if (mildred == currMax)
        {
          if (!mHighest) {
            count++;
            mHighest = true;
            bHighest = false;
            eHighest = false;
          }
        }
        if (elsie == currMax)
        {
          if (!eHighest) {
            count++;
            eHighest = true;
            bHighest = false;
            mHighest = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fout << count << endl;
}
```

Here is my launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
    "setupCommands": [
      {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
      }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
  }
]
```

}

I'm using MinGw and Coderunner.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can't actually see which is line 39. Can you add a comment next to that line?

Comment: Just added it. Thanks!

Comment: n must be an integer. Is that the case?

Comment: Update: I removed one of the "watch" variables (names[i]), and it works now. Thanks for all the help!